# Does STM32 HAL_UART_Transmit_IT() help save CPU time?

Tags: stm32, interrupt, uart

HAL_UART_Receive_IT() helps save CPU time.
How about HAL_UART_Transmit_IT()? Does HAL_UART_Transmit_IT() help save CPU time?
What is the diferrence between UART Transmit in Blocking mode and Interrupt Mode?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, interrupt-based operations, apart from extreme cases irrelevant for this discussion, allow you to utilize CPU much more efficiently.

Imagine you want to send one byte over UART at 9600 baudrate. 1 bit takes roughly 100us to send over wire (rounded 9600 to 10000 for napkin math), so shifting out 1 character - 8 bits plus start plus end would take in the neighborhood of 0.1ms*10 = 1ms. All this time your CPU will basically wait for the "byte sent" flag and do nothing else. It will keep polling that flag (effectively, an integer at a specific hardwired memory address) as quickly as the processor and memory can, even though you know that unless someone suddenly chops the wire mid-transmission, nothing will happen for a whole millisecond (which is literally thousands of CPU cycles for MHz-frequency MCU!).

Instead, there is an interrupt approach: your CPU loads the data into UART and says "alright, UART, I'm gonna do some other stuff right now, let me know when you are done with it". You load the byte in UART and your code immediately executes the code after it, it doesn't wait for the transmission to end or for any event to happen. Whenever some event happens - byte sent, or bus error, or another event (you can configure what events trigger interrupts or not), your CPU pauses whatever it's doing right now, regardless of what it is, and executes an interrupt handler function, after that the CPU returns to where it was and continues as if nothing happened.

Some properties of blocking approach, off the top of my head, without particular order:

1. Very easy to implement (is usually the first thing you implement with a new peripheral).
2. Data consistency is more or less guaranteed - if you told it to receive 4 characters, the receive function will only return when 4 characters are actually received. If you told it to send 4 characters, it will return only when all characters are physically sent out.
3. Perfect for test projects, small projects where few peripherals move data around, and there are no strict timing requirements.
4. If you have multiple peripherals, such as UART, I2C, SPI, timings can become an issue - you spend a lot of quick MHz-speed CPU waiting for slow kHz-speed communications. Similarly, if you do a lot of number crunching, you lose precious computation time.
5. It operates within thread context - you can create local data in your function (on stack or wherever you want) and simply send it straight from there, or create a receive buffer on stack and receive data into it. See point 4. for interrupts to see how interrupt-based drivers handle it. In some situations, this property of blocking driver can be very convenient (although it's nothing a good interrupt-based driver can't do, it takes more work).

A few things to say about interrupt approach:

1. A well-implemented interrupt-based driver is very robust and can handle peripheral events without locking up the CPU or peripheral (in case of errors too).
2. Interrupt-based driver functions return immediately, so you're free to crunch numbers or be on time for time-critical tasks, while the data is being sent out or received.
3. Data inconsistency can become an issue. You no longer wait for all the data to arrive or to be sent. The final byte will be sent or received at some point in the future. Make sure you work on/with up-to-date data.
4. Interrupt handlers exist outside the thread context - meaning, they are pretty much static/global functions, they have no access to variables you created in your main() function and anything it calls. Which means, you need to come up with a way for an interrupt handler to access the data you want to send/receive. A basic solution could be a global buffer array and/or some kind of global structure, which will keep track of what and where in memory to send data from (to the outside) and receive data to (from the outside). Also, there should be a way to signal if the transmission actually finished, so you know the data is up to date.
5. Interrupt-based driver is basically a state machine manager, which means it gets very messy very fast, especially if you don't have much experience at it. It's a step to event-driven programming, so it can take some adjustment to how you think in the context of peripheral behavior.
6. Interrupt-based drivers typically (not always, depends on peripheral and its configuration) work on a single unit of data at a time - for UART, the CPU will get an interrupt when every single byte is sent, and the CPU is then supposed to pause its thread, switch to interrupt handler, load the next byte manually into UART, and then get back to whatever it was doing in the main thread. The further development of this idea is DMA, which can automatically serve new bytes to UART (or other peripherals) even without CPU, but it's outside the scope of this discussion.

Remember, there is nothing wrong in using a blocking driver, if it suits your specific application. It's easy to write, the code is usually tidier and more intelligible (read "simple"), and it uses simpler data structures (if any), as well as near-guarantees data consistency. It's also perfect for learning a new peripheral. Before you handle a million peripheral events, it's good to get a taste of what the peripheral can do.

Comment: Your answer is very detailed. Now I understood. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

`HAL_UART_Transmit()` (the blocking version) won't return until all the characters have been transmitted. If you want to wait until they've all been sent, and have nothing else to do in the meantime, you might as well use this.

`HAL_UART_Transmit_IT()` will return immediately (before all the characters have been sent), and will send the characters "in the background". You'd need to poll the HAL to find out when it has finished. It will still use some CPU time to service the interrupts and transmit characters, but you can use the CPU to do other things at the same time. (Not really at the same time, but a crude approximation of multi-tasking.) So you *could* use this if you have other things you need to do while the transmit is taking place.

I've never found a good use for the `_IT()` versions of the HAL functions. If you want this kind of non-blocking functionality, using the `_DMA()` version of the function will give you it, with less overhead, and you don't need to worry about interrupt priorities etc.